# How to bind function in constructor that has a parameter in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here's my function:

```
remove(element)
{   
    this.setState({ search: this.state.search.filter( item => item !== element ) }); 
}
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). 
Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

If I have it set up like this:

```
constructor()
{
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
}
render() 
{   
    return (
        <div>
            { this.state.search.map( (item, index) =>  
                (   
                    <button key={index} onClick={this.remove(item)}>{item.search}: {item.text}</button>
                ))  
            }   
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But if works fine if I remove the binding (well doesn't really matter) from the constructor and change the button line to this:

```
<button key={index} onClick={this.remove.bind(this, item)}>{item.search}: {item.text}</button>
```

So my question is, is there a way to bind it in the constructor so that it can take on the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `this.remove(item)` and `this.remove.bind(this, item)` is that the first *calls* the function while the second creates a new function.

> So my question is, is there a way to bind it in the constructor so that it can take on the parameter?

You can use `this.remove.bind(this, item)` *and* perform the binding the constructor, though it is unnecessary.

If you want to pass `item` to the event handler, then you *have to* create a new function in `.map` that can access `item`, with your current setup. This can be done via `.bind` or via a closure. In either case, binding in the constructor is simply not necessary.

You can only avoid creating a new function if provide `item` in a different way, e.g. wrapping the button with another component that takes `item` as a prop (therefore pushing the function creation further down):

```
function Button({item, onClick}) {
  return <button onClick={() => onClick(item)}>{item.search}: {item.text}</button>;
}

class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor()
  {
      this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
  }

  render() 
  {   
      return (
          <div>
              { this.state.search.map( (item, index) =>  
                  (   
                      <Button key={index} onClick={this.remove} item={item} />
                  ))  
              }   
              </div>
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just read that it was better practicing principles to bind it at the start :\

Comment: That's correct, but that only works if you are passing the function directly to another component. Think about it: You have a *single* function `this.remove`. You want this function to be executed *n times* with a different `item` value. You either have to create *n* functions that call `this.remove` with the correct `item` value, or push the function invocation further down the stack.